# Bought Laravel Package, Package is running Laravel 6.x

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2, laravel-admin, laravel-package

I'm having trouble with installation of this here package i bought
[RedPrint Laravel App Builder CRUD Generator Plus](https://gplsoftware.com/shop/redprint-laravel-app-builder-crud-generator-plus/)

When I download the zip file and then in the terminal I can't do either

```
Composer install
or
npm install && npm run dev
or
php artisan migrate
```

Yes, I do have every requirements installed, and I do have multiple Laravel 8 projects installed perfectly fine without any errors.

Here's some errors you can read through if you want to:

### Command Error Log: Composer install

```
Administrator@WIN-S08NCUSF4DR MINGW64 /d/redprint-v1.6.32
$ composer install
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/cache is locked to version v1.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/cache v1.8.0 requires php ~7.1 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - doctrine/dbal is locked to version v2.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/dbal v2.8.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - doctrine/event-manager is locked to version v1.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/event-manager v1.0.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - doctrine/inflector is locked to version v1.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v5.7.12 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.12 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - opis/closure is locked to version 3.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - opis/closure 3.1.1 requires php ^5.4 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 7
    - paragonie/random_compat is locked to version v9.99.99 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99 requires php ^7 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 8
    - ramsey/uuid is locked to version 3.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - ramsey/uuid 3.8.0 requires php ^5.4 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 9
    - symfony/console is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/console v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 10
    - symfony/css-selector is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/css-selector v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 11
    - symfony/debug is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/debug v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 12
    - symfony/event-dispatcher is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/event-dispatcher v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 13
    - symfony/finder is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/finder v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 14
    - symfony/http-foundation is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/http-foundation v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 15
    - symfony/http-kernel is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 16
    - symfony/process is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/process v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 17
    - symfony/routing is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/routing v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 18
    - symfony/translation is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/translation v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 19
    - symfony/var-dumper is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/var-dumper v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 20
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles is locked to version 2.2.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.1 requires php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 21
    - tymon/jwt-auth is locked to version 1.0.0-rc.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0-rc.3 requires php ^5.5.9 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 22
    - doctrine/instantiator is locked to version 1.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 23
    - filp/whoops is locked to version 2.3.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - filp/whoops 2.3.1 requires php ^5.5.9 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 24
    - fzaninotto/faker is locked to version v1.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - fzaninotto/faker v1.8.0 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 25
    - myclabs/deep-copy is locked to version 1.8.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - myclabs/deep-copy 1.8.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 26
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock is locked to version 4.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 27
    - phpdocumentor/type-resolver is locked to version 0.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpdocumentor/type-resolver 0.4.0 requires php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 28
    - phpspec/prophecy is locked to version 1.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpspec/prophecy 1.8.0 requires php ^5.3|^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 29
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage is locked to version 4.0.8 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 30
    - phpunit/php-timer is locked to version 1.0.9 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/php-timer 1.0.9 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 31
    - phpunit/php-token-stream is locked to version 2.0.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/php-token-stream 2.0.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 32
    - phpunit/phpunit is locked to version 5.7.27 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.27 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 33
    - phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is locked to version 3.4.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 3.4.4 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 34
    - sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup is locked to version 1.0.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup 1.0.1 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 35
    - sebastian/diff is locked to version 1.4.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sebastian/diff 1.4.3 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 36
    - sebastian/environment is locked to version 2.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sebastian/environment 2.0.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 37
    - symfony/yaml is locked to version v4.1.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/yaml v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 38
    - webmozart/assert is locked to version 1.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - webmozart/assert 1.3.0 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 39
    - laravel/framework v5.7.12 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - shah-newaz/redprint-unity 0.9.15 requires laravel/framework ^5.6 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.12].
    - shah-newaz/redprint-unity is locked to version 0.9.15 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

### Command Error Log: npm install && npm run dev

```
Administrator@WIN-S08NCUSF4DR MINGW64 /d/redprint-v1.6.32
$ npm install && npm run dev
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'got@5.7.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=0.10.0 <7' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.1.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.4: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated boom@4.3.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated boom@5.2.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@3.1.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated sntp@2.0.2: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated json3@3.3.2: Please use the native JSON object instead of JSON 3
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.0.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated is-buffer@1.1.5: This version of 'is-buffer' is out-of-date. You must update to v1.1.6 or newer
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.5.1: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated clone@1.0.2: XSS vulnerability fixed in v1.0.3
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.1: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN deprecated hawk@6.0.2: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.1.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.1.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.83.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.1: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.16.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated buffer@4.9.1: This version of 'buffer' is out-of-date. You must update to v4.9.2 or newer
npm WARN deprecated svgo@0.7.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.5.1: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\redprint-v1.6.32\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.20348
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\redprint-v1.6.32\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\redprint-v1.6.32\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-03T01_28_19_039Z-debug.log
```

### Command Error Log: php artisan migrate

```
Administrator@WIN-S08NCUSF4DR MINGW64 /d/redprint-v1.6.32
$ php artisan migrate
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:838
Stack trace:
#0 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(838): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Method Reflecti...', 'D:\\redprint-v1....', 838)
#1 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(807): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#2 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Exceptions\\...')
#3 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array)
#4 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array)
#5 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(264): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array)
#6 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(776): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#7 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#8 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
#9 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
#10 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(159): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#11 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(101): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->getExceptionHandler()
#12 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderForConsole(Object(ErrorException))
#13 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(ErrorException))
#14 {main}
  thrown in D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 838
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:838
Stack trace:
#0 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(838): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Method Reflecti...', 'D:\\redprint-v1....', 838)
#1 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(807): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#2 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Exceptions\\...')
#3 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array)
#4 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array)
#5 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(264): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array)
#6 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(776): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#7 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#8 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
#9 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
#10 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(159): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#11 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(101): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->getExceptionHandler()
#12 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderForConsole(Object(ErrorException))
#13 D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(123): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(ErrorException))
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
#15 {main}
  thrown in D:\redprint-v1.6.32\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 838
```

Comment: the version of the software isn't compatible with PHP 8 ... this is trying to use version 5.7 of the Laravel framework not 6 btw  `laravel/framework v5.7.12 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.13) does not satisfy that requirement.`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am not sure why your question is downvoted 2 times... It's a perfectly fine question in my opinion, but to be honest, the answer is right there in the error log. I've upvoted it once. Reading and understanding error logs is a really important skill. Don't skim over those errors. Often times they tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah okay thanks guys for helping.

I understood the error logs ok at least i thought i did. I just didnt understand why php 8 wouldnt work becuse it should technically have all features php 7 had so i didnt see why it shouldnt work so i thought it had to be something else.

Thank you all for the help :-)

Comment: Both `^7.1` and `~7.1` mean that it will work with  `>=7.1.0 <8.0.0` ([more info](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#tilde-version-range-)). The idea with semantic versioning is that a major release (the first number) could introduce breaking changes. Since the versions of the packages you have installed would have been created before PHP 8 even had a release candidate, it wouldn't be safe to assume that the packages would still definitely work so they were constrained. You could try running `composer update` but I imagine there will still be some work/debugging to follow.